# GORM doesnt update boolean field to false

Tags: go, go-gorm

On `updates` gorm doesnt update boolean type to `false`. By default it updates to `true`, but when i try to update to `false` not changes. I dont see any errors also. What can be the issue ?

```
type Attendee struct {
    ID             uint   `gorm:"primary_key" gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"id,omitempty" mapstructure:"id" csv:"ID"`
    Email          string `json:"email,omitempty" mapstructure:"email" csv:"Email,required"`

    ShowDirectory  bool   `json:"show_directory,omitempty" gorm:"default:true" mapstructure:"show_directory" csv:"-"`
}


var attendee Attendee
// JSON.unmarshal lines here for the &attendee
if err := service.DB.Model(&attendee).Updates(Attendee{
        Email:         attendee.Email,
        ShowDirectory: false
}).Error; err != nil {
    return Attendee{}, err
}
```

**Alternate Solution:**

This works, but I am updating multiple attributies. So, I cant use this.

```
    att := Attendee{ID: 1}
    service.DB.Model(&att).Update("ShowDirectory", false)
```

Comment: That's documented and *intended* behaviour when using *structs*, you can use a map for properties that are affected by such a strange (IMO) design decision. https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-Changed-Fields (note the comments)

Comment: @mkopriva ohhh, Thanks, just noticed it. It says `false are blank values of their types` on struct usage

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As @mkopriva mentioned, by GORM [Documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns)

> ```golang
> // Update attributes with `struct`, will only update non-zero fields
> db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18, Active: false})
> // UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 > 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;
>
> // Update attributes with `map`
> db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"name": "hello", "age": 18, "actived": false})
> // UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, actived=false, updated_at='2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id=111;
> ```
>
> > **NOTE** When update with struct, GORM will only update non-zero fields, you might want to use `map` to update attributes or use `Select` to specify fields to update

**Solved:**

```
if err := service.DB.Model(&attendee).Updates(map[string]interface{}{
    "Email":          attendee.Email,
    "ShowDirectory": false
}).Error; err != nil {
    return Attendee{}, err
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Another convenient way would be making that field as a pointer.

**NOTE all fields having a zero value, like 0, '', false or other zero values, won’t be saved into the database but will use its default value. If you want to avoid this, consider using a pointer type or scanner/valuer**[Link](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html)

In your case, the model would look like:

```
type Attendee struct {
        ID             uint   `gorm:"primary_key" gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"id,omitempty" mapstructure:"id" csv:"ID"`
        Email          string `json:"email,omitempty" mapstructure:"email" csv:"Email,required"`
    
        ShowDirectory  *bool   `json:"show_directory,omitempty" gorm:"default:true" mapstructure:"show_directory" csv:"-"`
}
```

Comment: I prefer this method as I can still update my records with my models instead of using a `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: can confirm this works, you just saved me after a whole day of debugging

Comment: Another way is to set the default constraint to `false`. Although, you will have to explicitly specify the value for `ShowDirectory`. Either way, it's just terrible it works like that.

Comment: You can format your GORM attribute details as a bool type with the pointer as well, but its not necessary and this maps with and without.

gorm:"default:true;type:bool"

Answer (score 3):

As it's mentioned from the document, to set a falsy value you need to use `map` or select the columns you need.

> When update with struct, GORM will only update non-zero fields, you might want to use map to update attributes or use Select to specify fields to update

```golang
// Select with Struct (select zero value fields)
db.Model(&user).Select("Name", "Age").Updates(User{Name: "new_name", Age: 0})
// UPDATE users SET name='new_name', age=0 WHERE id=111;
```

or you can select all columns:

```golang
// Select all fields (select all fields include zero value fields)
db.Model(&user).Select("*").Update(User{Name: "jinzhu", Role: "admin", Age: 0})
```

Comment: if you want to update partially, `select *` which fetch all columns is a bad idea,  because other columns will be set zero value

Answer (score 0):

You should write gorm type in your struct, something like this:
`gorm:"type:boolean; column:column_name"`
and for sure it will work!

Comment: check documentation, it says `false are blank values of their types` and blank value is `false` always

Comment: Ill try next time, when i face it :)

Comment: Didn't for me. Can anyone else confirm if this worked for them?  Gorm v1.20.12

Comment: Can confirm it didn't work for me too. `v1.20.12`

Comment: The problem is not if the model is defined correctly or not, the problem is that GORM doesn't work with boolean columns that are set as default `true`.
P.S. The issue still exists in GORM +2 versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not use go struct for updating the non-zero fields such as boolean:false**

The below code will not update `Active: false` in your database and gorm simply ignore

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18, Active: false})
// UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, updated_at = '2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id = 111;
```

The below code will update the `Active: false`

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"name": "hello", "age": 18, "actived": false})
// UPDATE users SET name='hello', age=18, actived=false, updated_at='2013-11-17 21:34:10' WHERE id=111;
```

> Use Map instead of go struct

Comment: Have you seen my answer? And whats difference between mine?

Comment: You said without a clear explanation and a best example and comparison, I just added more explanation. You know I faced the same issue and landed to this question but your answer didn’t help when I first saw your answer dint saw the actual difference at the first sight, trust me for few  users my answer will help and that contains good explanation so I decided to write one more answer. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** if you want to update all fields, use the `Save()` method instead of `Updates()`.

As other answers have pointed out, `Updates()` will not update zero field values. That's because GORM can't tell the difference between
`Attendee{Email: "...", ShowDirectory: false}` and `Attendee{Email: "..."}`.

To update all field values and avoid specifying field names as strings, you can read the record, change field values, and save the record. It's better to do this in a single transaction to avoid race conditions:

```golang
err := db.Transaction(func(db *gorm.DB) error {

    // read the existing record
    var a Attendee
    if res := db.Where("id = ?", attendeeId).First(&a); res.Error != nil {
        return err
    }

    // update the fields
    a.Email = newEmail
    a.ShowDirectory = newShowDirectory 

    // save the record
    if res := db.Save(&a); res.Error != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pointer field and mapstructure tag.
so when you need a update data, you can implement a function like this:

```
func (m *Model) ToMap() map[string]interface{} {
    var updateData map[string]interface{}
    err := mapstructure.Decode(m, &updateData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    return updateData
}
```

This implementation also work when you create a Filter struct

```
query := txn.Model(&Model{}).Clauses(clause.Returning{})
conditions := filter.ToMap()
if len(conditions) > 0 {
    query = query.Where(conditions)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `Select(*)

```golang
db.Model(&user).Select("*").Update(User{Name: "jinzhu", Role: "admin", Age: 0})
```

This way is much more simpler than others.

Comment: This throws "cannot convert map[] to Text" for string attributes unfortunately..